# Ng-repeat vs creating dom in jquery

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to keep a whole menu in javascript so that it loads up fast for the users ( i know it goes in the memory but it's not so bad and it should not be growing any time soon ).

my issue is that if I generate it in simple javascript, it gets created almost instantly while if I use ng-repeat, it is much much slower.

Its a bit messy and I simplified it cause I'm also adding classes, and other attributes but you should get the gist of it from this..

I know I can further simplify the following repetitive html by using directives, but the performance will be the same, so bear with me.

---

Using ng-repeat (4 nested for loops):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in catList">
        <a> <span> {{item.name}}</span> </a>
        <div ng-if="item.children.length > 0">
            <div>
                <div ng-repeat="item2 in item.children">
                    <a> <span> {{item2.name}}</span> </a>
                    <div ng-if="item2.children.length > 0">
                        <div>
                            <div ng-repeat="item3 in item2.children">
                                <a> <span> {{item3.name}}</span> </a>
                                <div ng-if="item3.children.length > 0">
                                    <div>
                                        <div ng-repeat="item4 in item3.children">
                                            <a> <span> {{item4.name}}</span></a>
                                            <div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

(check console for the time it takes to process and render the list - I was not too sure when to start timing it in angular. I know 'app.run(function(){})' runs after everything has loaded, but I'm not sure when everything starts)

http://jsfiddle.net/0m0qod3u/1/

---

And now for generating it by generating dom elements dynamically in js/jquery:

```
function printCategoriesMenu(list, fatherElem, idObj, currPath, level){
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        var currElem = list[i];

        var thisElemsPath = currPath;
        if (level == 0){
            thisElemsPath += currElem.name;
        } else {
            thisElemsPath += "/" + currElem.name;
        }

        var el_a = document.createElement('a');

        var el_span = document.createElement("span");
        el_span.textContent = currElem.name;

        el_a.appendChild(el_span);

        var el_div = document.createElement("div");
        el_div.setAttribute("id", idObj.eid + "_children");

        fatherElem.appendChild(el_a);
        fatherElem.appendChild(el_div);

        idObj.eid++;

        if (currElem.children.length > 0){
            printCategoriesMenu( currElem.children, el_div, idObj, thisElemsPath, level+1 );
        }
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var start = window.performance.now();
    console.log("START TIME: " + start);
    printCategoriesMenu( catList, document.getElementById('categoriesList'), {'eid': 0}, "", 0 );
    var end = window.performance.now();
    console.log("END TIME: " + end);
    console.log("time: " + (end - start) );
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wp4jz8qv/

---

After I add the various attributes (class, ng-click/onclick..), the performance of it using ng repeat is even worse and has a bad bad delay when first loading the page..

What I've tried to do to improve the performance of it using angular so far:

- Using ng-repeat, there would be a lot of 2 way bindings happening so I tried using 'bindonce' and it didn't seem to affect the performance much, if at all.
- Tried using 'track by', no difference in performance.
- Tried using limitTo in order to generate the subcategories at a different time (I would first generate the first level and the second; when the user would select a first category, the third subcategories will load, etc). This worked much better, but there would be a delay when generating the subcategory levels as the user selects one category (ng repeat is synchronous and this did not look good - looked like the page froze for 1-2 seconds :( )
- It is inconvenient to keep the menu generation part in a js/jquery file while everything else is an angular app, so I tried generating the dom dynamically ( so NOT using ng-repeat ) in my controller via a directive thinking I'd be able to get the same performance that js/jquery offered. Unfortunately, it was pretty much just as slow as using ng-repeat (sorry I don't have a jsfiddle for this part ). This part was really dissappointing :(

I saw a few posts on optimizing the performance of ng-repeat and watching for how many watchers get created for each element/etc.. I'd like to do that as soon as I am done past a point with this project.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks,
Mihai